# Failed to authenticate since user account is locked, Springboot security authentication error

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot-security

"I am relatively new to Java and Spring boot applications, I am trying to follow a YouTube tutorial.
I have created the signup and login endpoints and testing using postman, and signup works and the details are being created in database with encrypted password. When I try to use the same credentials to test the login endpoint. I am getting a 403 request forbidden error. I placed a debugger in the spring security."

"Below is the code for my JWTauthenticationFilter":

````
    ```@Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JWTUtil jwtUtil;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    @NonNull HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException,     IOException {
        final String authHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(authHeader) || !StringUtils.startsWith(authHeader, "Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtUtil.extractUserName(jwt);
        if(StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(userEmail)
        && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails =        userService.userDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtUtil.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new     WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                context.setAuthentication(authToken);
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }


    }```
````

Below is the code for my WebSecurityConfiguration:

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {
private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(request ->
                request.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                            .requestMatchers("/api/customer/**").hasAnyAuthority(UserRole.CUSTOMER.name())
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()).sessionManagement(manger ->
                manger.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProviders())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter,     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviders() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration     authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    }```

</code></pre>

I tried using webresources and different GPTs and there seems to be no clarity with what is going on...
I did exactly as I was shown in the tutorial.

And the below is the console : I hope someone figures it out, I have tried extensively looking for a solution...

<pre><code>

```2024-03-21T14:58:27.212-04:00 DEBUG 14564 --- [nio-9000-exec-3]           o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : Securing POST /api/auth/login </code>`
<code>2024-03-21T14:58:27.213-04:00 DEBUG 14564 --- [nio-9000-exec-3]   o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext</code>
<code>2024-03-21T14:58:27.213-04:00 DEBUG 14564 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /api/auth/login</code>
<code>2024-03-21T14:58:27.317-04:00 DEBUG 14564 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since user account is locked</code>
<code>2024-03-21T14:58:27.320-04:00 DEBUG 14564 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access</code>
<code>2024-03-21T14:58:27.325-04:00 DEBUG 14564 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error</code>
<code>2024-03-21T14:58:27.325-04:00 DEBUG 14564 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext</code>
<code>2024-03-21T14:58:27.327-04:00 DEBUG 14564 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access</code>
<code>2024-03-21T15:54:37.576-04:00  INFO 14564 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'```

</code></pre>